# Are the LCD screens on Canon G9 and G9X the same?

Tags: canon, lcd

I want to install screen protector on my G9X.
Problem is that I want it sooner, but (suddenly) there are no suitable options in nearby shops.
Optimal by price & delivery time deal for remote order that I've found is for G9.

So, my question is here. Is LCD screen protector for G9 fits for G9X?

I've tried to google it by myself, unfortunately no luck. I've figured out that both models has 3" LCD, but it's diagonal and I'm not sure that screen width and height are the same.

If you have Canon G9 (or know somebody who has it), I'll really appreciate if you write here it's LCD width and height measurements. I think it should be measurements of whole display (glass including dead zones by it's perimeter), not only working screen.

For example, for G9X: 3" (~76 mm) is working screen diagonal, and whole display diagonal is 92mm. Width 72mm and height is 52mm.

Comment: Knowing the external dimensions will give you no indication of whether they are compatible in any other way. Fixings, cabling might be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No, they are not.** The G9 X has a 3" LCD with 3:2 aspect-ratio while the G9 has a 3" LCD with 4:3 aspect-ratio.

The G9 uses a 4:3 screen because that aspect-ratio matches its sensor. Both images and video from the G9 have the same aspect-ratio, so there is little need to use a screen of a different aspect.

The sensor on the G9 X has a 3:2 aspect-ratio and hence the screen matches its framing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, displays are different, but I still have no measurements to be sure

G9 [image]
G9X [image]

Comment: You can use camerasize.com to get [a side-by-side of the two cameras to scale](http://camerasize.com/compact/#191,636,ha,b). Maybe upgrade your graphics to a screengrab from there? Looks like different aspect ratios.